# Symlink storage link from Laravel doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, laravel

I'm uploading an image with laravel using this code:

```
$logoPath = $request->file('logo')->store('uploads/clients');
```

It works fine, the file is uploaded to `storage/app/uploads/clients/`.

Then, I run the command `php artisan storage:link` to create the symlink in public and its created successfully. The problem is that this symlink shows only the files in "storage/app/public" but, as i said, my images are being saved in `storage/app/uploads/clients`.

I already did this process in others projects and it works fine, I don't really know what I did different this time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using the default disk which is `local` that stores the files in `storage/app` directory as configured in `config/filesystems.php`, but what you want is `public` disk which stores the files in `storage/app/public` that is linked to the public directory by running `php artisan storage:link`.

So here are some solutions:

- Specify which disk you want to use:

  ```
   $request->file('logo')->store('uploads/clients', ['disk' => 'public']);
  ```

**OR**

- Create a new disk in `config/filesystems.php` and link it with your `uploads/clients` then change the default `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` in `config/filesystems.php` to the new disk.

**OR**

- Change the default `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` to `public` in `config/filesystems.php`.